# Referencing and dereferencing pointers

Tags: c

I got a fairly easy question that I just need to clarity on.

```
int R3;
int **R4;
R3 = (*(*R4))+4;
```

So my question is, R4 is a pointer to a pointer, correct?  So in the last statement does this mean increment the pointer's address by 4 or add 4 to the value which R4 points to?

Answer (score 5):

It means add 4 to the value. `R4` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. `*R4` dereferences the first pointer, so it is a pointer to an `int`. Likewise `*(*R4)` dereferences the remaining pointer, and you are given the value of the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> R4 is a pointer to a pointer, correct?

Yes, that is correct. `R4` is a pointer to pointer to `int`.

The last statement consists of an assignment to `R3`. This means that the value of `R3` is being changed. The value being assigned is the expression `(*(*R4))+4`. `(*(*R4))` yields the value that is stored in `**R4` (an `int`), so the value of the expression is equal to the value of whatever `int` is indirectly referenced by `R4` plus 4. `R4` is never modified.